# Is there any example that implement Ckeditor (browse server - upload) functions in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor

it's my first question to this nice site :) ... i use ckeditor.com in my asp.net web site and it have a great features but if any check the full feature example when inserting image you have two feature ( upload to server - browse server and choose image ) as shown in below image

http://i45.tinypic.com/2rmp5ds.jpg

My Questions : 
1- Browse Server function integrate with another product called CKfinder .. i don't want to use it i search for such one but in asp.net and can be integrating with ckeditor ? 
2- is there an example Upload image function that can save in SQL DB and can be integrated with ckeditor ?

Thanks in advance for your expected cooperations

Answer (score 0):

I don know much about CK Editor, but I would like to suggest you  to take a look at free text box, it has the same features and u can manage to upload photo as well.

Comment: According to http://freetextbox.com/demos/ there isn't a way to upload image during insert image

Comment: We can set the ImageGalleryUrl property where you can manage ur images.  If you need more info, I can provide some example. :)

Comment: Could you please provide me with an example

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Ckfinder. Just use below code in ckeditor.replace it will give you browse server button on image window and upload functionality by not integrating with any other plugin. These are all Ckeditor functions.

```
filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : your image loading path
            filebrowserWindowWidth : '640',
        filebrowserWindowHeight : '480',
    filebrowserImageUploadUrl : '/uploader/upload.php?type=Images',
```